# Topic Extraction Using Gensim

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, lda, topic-modeling

I am trying to extract topics using Gensim library, LDA model from Persona-Chat dataset. After pre-processing part, I try to find the best number of topic in order to get the best keywords regarding to the topics.

So, for that I ran the code for different number of topics such as; 50-100-150-200 and 250.

The Coherence Score increases whenever number of topics are increased and at the same time, Perplexity Score decreases as well. So, from these information I understood I had to use 250, because as far as I know, Perplexity should be small and Coherence should be high. Below, you can see the scores of each number of topics (K)

- K is 50, Coherence Score is 0.5674564036353904 and Perplexity is
  -30.41004925196529
- K is 100, Coherence Score is 0.7057459566697354 and Perplexity is
  -152.65336624931487
- K is 150, Coherence Score is 0.8342139447628544 and Perplexity is
  -298.6829528808594
- K is 200, Coherence Score is 0.8342139447628546 and Perplexity is
  -398.1058654785156
- K is 250, Coherence Score is 0.8342139447628545 and Perplexity is
  -497.6555480957031

However, whenever I used 250 number of topics, my keywords have 0 weight and they are repeated in every topic.

- (0, '0.000*"white" + 0.000*"chalk" + 0.000*"princeton" +
  0.000*"gymnast" + 0.000*"vanilla" + 0.000*"rain" + 0.000*"cow" + 0.000*"ds" + 0.000*"employed" + 0.000*"dirty"')
- (1, '0.000*"white" + 0.000*"chalk" + 0.000*"princeton" +
  0.000*"gymnast" + 0.000*"vanilla" + 0.000*"rain" + 0.000*"cow" + 0.000*"ds" + 0.000*"employed" + 0.000*"dirty"')
- (2, '0.000*"white" + 0.000*"chalk" + 0.000*"princeton" +
  0.000*"gymnast" + 0.000*"vanilla" + 0.000*"rain" + 0.000*"cow" + 0.000*"ds" + 0.000*"employed" + 0.000*"dirty"')

I made some research and I found out that if keywords are repeated then maybe my number of topics are too much. So I decreased my number of topics from 250 to 50 but I want to know, is there any ways to fix this?

Since, the Perplexity and Coherence Scores shows that LDA model would work better with 250 number of  topics.

Below you can find the code as well.

```
personality_dictionary = Dictionary(df['persona_sentences'])
corpus_personality = [personality_dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in df['persona_sentences']]
lda = LdaModel(corpus=corpus_personality, num_topics=50, id2word=personality_dictionary)
lda_personality_topics = lda.print_topics(num_words=10, num_topics = -1)
for topic in lda_personality_topics:
    print(topic)
```

Best regards,

Comment: I'm running into the same phenomenon when num_topics is set too high. Did you ever figure out what was going on?